# How to write a cheapestStoreForRecipe function in the most efficient way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

How I solve this in the most efficient way? Should we work with .reduce() and these methods or should we use the classic for in loop to iterate over the keys in allStore and calculate it with the recipe?

```
var soup = { //recipe
    potato: 3,
    onion: 1,
    corn: 5
};

var edoka = {
    cheese: 8,
    corn: 3,
    meat: 6,
    onion: 4,
    pea: 1,
    oregano: 7,
    potato: 5,
    tomato: 6
};

var were = {
    cheese: 6,
    corn: 2,
    meat: 9,
    onion: 5,
    pea: 2,
    oregano: 6,
    potato: 3,
    tomato: 3
};

var brutto = {
    cheese: 6,
    corn: 2,
    meat: 9,
    onion: 5,
    pea: 2,
    oregano: 8,
    potato: 3,
    tomato: 4
};

var allStores = { // this is an example of a "storeCollection"
    Brutto: brutto,
    Edoka: edoka,
    Were: were,
};

function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection){
    // make it return the key for the store in storeCollection
    // that has the cheapest total cost for recipe. Feel free
    // to use costOfRecipe inside this function!
}
```

Comment: I think that is your homework and you just gave us the code that belongs to it. Where is your own code and your try to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way to solve your problem:

```
function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection) {
    let cheapestStore;
    let cheapestPrice = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    Object.keys(storeCollection).forEach(store => {
        let costOfRecipe = 0;

        Object.keys(recipe).forEach(ingredient => {
            costOfRecipe += recipe[ingredient] || 0;
        });

        if (costOfRecipe < cheapestPrice) {
            cheapestPrice = costOfRecipe;
            cheapestStore = store;
        }
    });

    return cheapestStore;
}
```

Some argue that `for` is more efficient than `forEach`. Others say this is no longer true, in mordern environments. I prefer the `forEach` implementation for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will help you explore how to use `Array.reduce`. It may not be the most efficient, but from here you can devise your own solution. To make this more efficient, you should continue working with the concept to get the results you need in terms of processing time or complexity.

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/StainedSickNet)

`cheapestStoreForRecipe` accepts two arguments: `recipe` and `storeCollection`. The method returns a list of stores with invoices for the recipe that includes the cost of each item and total cost.

First, `storeCollection` iterates through each store in the collection. Second, for each store the recipe items are iterated through. When there is a recipe item that matches a store inventory item, the `quantity`, `unit`, and `total` values for the item are calculated; then the total cost of each recipe is calculated.

```
function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection){
  return Object.entries(storeCollection)
    .reduce((_storeCollection, [storeName, storeInventory]) => {
      let storeInvoice = Object.entries(recipe)
        .reduce((_recipe, [itemName, itemQuantity]) => {
          let storeInventoryItem = storeInventory[itemName]
          if(storeInventoryItem) {
            _recipe.invoice[itemName] = {
              quantity: itemQuantity,
              unit: storeInventoryItem,
              total: itemQuantity * storeInventoryItem,
            }
            _recipe.total += _recipe.invoice[itemName].total
          }
          return _recipe
        }, {
          invoice: {},
          total: 0,
        })
      _storeCollection[storeName] = storeInvoice
      return _storeCollection
    }, {
      Brutto: {},
      Edoka: {},
      Were: {},
    })
}
```

```
{
  "Brutto": {
    "invoice": {
      "potato": {
        "quantity": 3, 
        "unit": 3,
        "total": 9
      },
      "onion": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit": 5,
        "total": 5
      },
      "corn": {
        "quantity": 5,
        "unit": 2,
        "total": 10
      }
    },
    "total": 24
  },
  "Edoka": {
    "invoice": {
      "potato": {
        "quantity": 3,
        "unit": 5,
        "total": 15
      },
      "onion": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit": 4,
        "total": 4
      },
      "corn": {
        "quantity": 5,
        "unit": 3,
        "total": 15
      }
    },
    "total": 34
  },
  "Were": {
    "invoice": {
      "potato": {
        "quantity": 3,
        "unit": 3,
        "total": 9
      },
      "onion": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit": 5,
        "total": 5
      },
      "corn": {
        "quantity": 5,
        "unit": 2,
        "total": 10
      }
    },
    "total": 24
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this personally, it's the most readable IMO (although that is subjective obviously). I would expect the performance to as good as any and a it's a good chance to use the fairly new Object.entries API.

```
function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection){
    let cheapest, cheapestStore;
    for (const [storeName, store] of Object.entries(allStores)) {
        let total = 0;
        for (const [ingredient, amnt] of Object.entries(recipe)) {
            total += store[ingredient] * amnt;
        }

        if (!cheapest || total < cheapest) {
            cheapest = total;
            cheapestStore = storeName;
        }
    }

    return cheapestStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the cost of a recipe you'll need to sum the values of an array made of the **intersection** of recipe keys and each store products keys. But that's your homework and you must do it  yourself.

Regarding the efficiency of different ways to sum the elements of an array, `for` is the most efficient in long arrays.

I made a small demo below comparing

- for
- for..of
- forEach
- reduce

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

const functionsObj = {
  usingFor: async(array) => {

    return new Promise(res => {
      let result = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result += array[i];
      }
      res(result);
    });
  },
  usingForeach: async(array) => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      let result = 0;
      array.forEach(number => {
        result += number;
      })
      res(result);
    });
  },

  usingReduce: async(array) => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      const result = array.reduce(add);
      res(result);
    });
  },
  usingForOf: async(array) => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      let result = 0;
      for (let i of array) {
        result += i;
      }
      res(result);
    });
  }
};
const Arr10M = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {
  Arr10M.push(
    1 + parseInt(40 * Math.random(), 10)
  );
}
const Arr10K = Arr10M.slice(0, 10000);

async function runTests(method, arr, attempts = 300) {
  let results = [];
  for (let attempt of arr.slice(0, attempts)) {
    performance.mark('start');
    await functionsObj[method](arr);
    performance.mark('end');
    results.push(performance.measure(method, 'start', 'end').duration);
    performance.clearMeasures();
    performance.clearMarks();
  }
  return new Promise(res => {
    let min = 1 * Number(Math.min(...results)).toFixed(6),
      max = 1 * Number(Math.max(...results)).toFixed(6);

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      res([min, max]);
    }, 1000 - 1 * max);
  });

}
(async() => {


  let results = {},
    methods = ['usingFor', 'usingForOf', 'usingReduce', 'usingForeach'];
  for (let method of methods) {
    let [
      min_10K_elements,
      max_10K_elements
    ] = await runTests(method, Arr10K), [
        min_10M_elements,
        max_10M_elements
      ] = await runTests(method, Arr10M, 3),
      result = {
        min_10K_elements,
        max_10K_elements,
        min_10M_elements,
        max_10M_elements
      };

    results[method] = result;
    console.log({
      method,
      ...result
    });
  }
  console.table(results);


  return;
})();
```

If you open the devtools in your browser, to see the results in a table, you'll notice `for` is consistently the fastest where as `reduce` and `forEach` are +- equal. The difference is negligible when testing arrays of 10K elements (and might be influenced by concurrent processes in the browser or even in your machine).

Testing an array of 10M elements, the performance of `for` is between 20x and 30x in comparison to `reduce` and `forEach`.

Clean code beats early overoptimization, but if your homework scores raw performance, you have now a real benchmark.